Keyboard problems with far2l file manager under Ubuntu 24.04 in Wayland session
I use the far2l file manager (this is a port of Far Manager on Linux). Ubuntu 24.04 was recently released, and it is in the repositories since 23.10. Unfortunately, there are two annoying bugs in the Wayland session: the response to keyboard button presses has a noticeable delay, and the ESC key has to be pressed twice. There are no such problems in X11 sessions. Maybe there are some workarounds?

There are several ways to work around whose issues:

Stay on X11

Run far2l with two additional parameters: far2l --nodetect=xi --ee

Run this patch: sudo perl -pi -e 's/XInputExtension/!InputExtension/g' /usr/lib/far2l/far2l_ttyx.broker
(you still have to use --ee switch)

Use the more recent version from Debian:


mkdir far
cd far
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/far2l/far2l_2.6.1~beta+ds-1_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/far2l/far2l-data_2.6.1~beta+ds-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
apt-cache policy far2l
(updating Ubuntu 24.04 version to 2.6.1 is in progress)
You can use the one you prefer.

Fix is released so now you can just do
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

